# Problem on Basic Combinations

Tags: combinations

A debate club consists of $6$ girls and 
$4$ boys. A team of $4$ members is to be selected from 
this club including the selection of a captain (from among these $4$ members) for the team. 
If the team has to include at most one boy, then the number of ways of selecting the team is?

My method was to use combinations:
$$\frac{4!}{3!} \cdot \frac{6!}{3!\,3!} + \frac {6!}{4!\,2!} = 95$$
But that is not the right answer. Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: In your method, you are not counting the number of choices for choosing a captain.

Comment: You have ignored that one of the selected members will be the captain.

Comment: I get it. There were 4 ways to select a captain amongst them, so the answer in effect would be 4(95) = 380.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE! Here is [a link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to a tutorial where you can learn how to make your posts look more attractive for other readers. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added the ways of choosing one boy and the ways of choosing 4 girls ignoring the boys; and in neither case have you distinguished different choices for the captain.

Your breakdown between 1 boy and 2 boys is a good start.

One boy gives you $\binom41$ choices for the boy, $\binom63$ choices for the girls, and $4$ choices for who is the captain.

No boys gives you $\binom64$ choices for the girls, times  $4$ choices for who is the captain.

The total is $320+60 = 380$ team selections.